# How to copy permissions across sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, permissions

Named ranges are duplicated when their sheet is duplicated. However, protected ranges are not.

I have 40 protected ranges on a sheet that I need to replicate six times, so I'm not really looking forward to defining 240 ranges.

Is there a way to keep the protected ranges when you replicate a sheet, or otherwise import them to the replicated sheet?